# MongoDB moving array of sub-documents to it's own collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to move an array of subdocuments into a collection of it's own keyed by the owner id. Currently, my collection is formed like this:

```
"_id": ObjectId("123"),
"username": "Bob Dole",
"logins": [{
  "_id": ObjectId("abc123"),
  "date": ISODate("2016")
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("def456"),
  "date": ISODate("2016")
}]
```

I'm looking for the best way to write a script that would loop over each user, and move each item in the logins array to it's own "logins" collection, as follows:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("abc123"),
    "_ownerId": ObjectId("123"),
    "date": ISODate("2016")
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("def567"),
    "_ownerId": ObjectId("123"),
    "date": ISODate("2016")
}
```

When the script ends, I'd like the login array to be removed entirely from all users.

Comment: I failed to see the elements from your array in your new collection

Comment: what is the source of _ownerId?  - it is not clear for me.

Comment: @user3100115 Thank you, updated.

Comment: @profesor79 -- really? Look at the _id of the first record.

Comment: haha - you edited your query when I was writing - nice timing Sir :-)

Comment: @profesor79 I never modified the ids, I just forgot to add the date to collection #2.

Answer (score 3):

this query will create new collection using aggregation framework
to see how it looks - just remove $out pipeline phase

```
db.thinking.aggregate([
{
    $unwind:"$logins"
},{
    $project:{
        _id:"$logins._id",
         _ownerId:"$_id",
        date:"$logins.date"
    }   
},
{ 
    $out: "newCollection" 
}
])
```

to delete array records - as suggested in comment:

```
db.thinking.update({},{ "$unset": { "logins": "" } },{ "multi": true })
```

Comment: Whilst I agree that `$out` is a good option for the "sub-documents" in a **new** collection, you really should not be using it to "re-shape" the master collection. You **cannot** "overwrite" the same collection name as the "source", and of course it would therefore result in "another collection". Anyhow `db.thinking.update({},{ "$unset": { "logins": "" } },{ "multi": true })` is **far** more efficient, as well as affecting the "source" directly.

Comment: @Neil Lunn thanks for hint,  I can see that I am a bit crazy about aggregation framework